# Simple MYSQL OR query not giving the correct amount of results

Tags: mysql

Okay, I have a very simple query like

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `colum_name` = 'value'
```

This is fine and I get a result that equals 22. When I run that same query with a different `value` I get a result of 177 but when I put it together with an `OR` statement the results don't add up.

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `colum_name` = 'value' OR `colum_name` = 'different_value'
```

I get a result of 210 when it should be 199. Am I missing something here?

This is the actual query

```
SELECT * FROM `fhdd_2_pricebook` WHERE `product2-na_pricebook__c` = '1' AND `product2-product_series__c` = 'Obstruction - High Int Kit' OR `product2-product_series__c` = 'Obstruction - Low Int'
```

Comment: You'll have to post the actual query.

Comment: And some sample data please?

Comment: by result you mean record count right?  and you're expecting 199 becuase 22+177=199 right? is the data changing under you? are column_name's both the same or are you looking at different columns?  I can see where you may have fewer but more seems odd.

Comment: Since you haven't shared the query, I'm just guessing here, but your issue might be: `WHERE <f1>='value' AND colum_name = 'value' OR colum_name='different_value'` but it should be `WHERE <f1>='value' AND (colum_name = 'value' OR colum_name='different_value')`

Comment: @xQbert Yes, I mean the record count and it is the same column.

Comment: 'OR' won't add the results for you, it'll simply retrieve the row which matches either of the values

Comment: @JNevill was right

Comment: Glad to hear that solved the problem. The issue is that when you omit the parentheses it will be interpreted like `WHERE (<f1>='value' AND colum_name = 'value') OR colum_name='different_value'` which will net you more records than you want.